# How could i declare two actions or with same path in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to declare this two actions with the same path, and both of them must be with POST method

```
lacarte_rest_validRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:validRsv }
    methods:  [POST]



lacarte_rest_cancelRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:cancelRsv }
    methods:  [POST]
```

Comment: how should that work ? where is the difference in the request ? sure you can handle this in one action, what are you trying ?

Comment: I need to execute two actions with same path

Comment: so you mean you request `/tableRsv` and you want both actions to be called ?

Comment: yes, if i can't do that, what should i do to call one of them with path:     /tableRsv/validRsv   and the other  path:     /tableRsv

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
lacarte_rest_validRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv/{response}
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:validAndCancelRsv }
    methods:  [POST]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are going to use the same path for 2 different actions: create or delete a reservation.

So try this:

```
lacarte_rest_validRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:validRsv }
    methods:  [POST]

lacarte_rest_cancelRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:cancelRsv }
    methods:  [DELETE]
```

Check out the [official documentation about using HTTP methods in Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html) for more details.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You cannot have two different behavior within the same excact path. 
Otherwise, you must have some optionnal parameters in the route configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo sad in comments you want one action for path /tableRsv/validRsv and other for /tableRsv
 So its simple:

```
lacarte_rest_validRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv/validRsv
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:validRsv }
    methods:  [POST]



lacarte_rest_cancelRsv:
    path:     /tableRsv
    defaults: { _controller: LacarteRestBundle:Rsv:cancelRsv }
    methods:  [POST]
```

If you want one url for two actions it can be done only with different http methods.